# Intrusion detection system on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, intrusion-detection

Hi i have a project i'm working on, i have some intrusion detection datasets stored in AWS (in S3) extension arff and pcap file, i tried to install SNORT on EC2 fowolling internet tutorial http://sublimerobots.com/2014/12/installing-snort-part-1/, but it's not the ideal solution.

I need to analyse this dataset in aws cloud and see detection rate....

I want to know if there is an IDS service or an exist IDS which i could run in aws to analyse thoses datasets.

Comment: And i want Intrusion detection System who work perfectly on offline mode and Could detail detection rate and false positive for every kind of attack (DOS,prob,ssh....)

Comment: This might help https://medium.com/@samuelabiodun/how-we-built-an-intrusion-detection-system-on-aws-using-open-source-tools-8b755e965d54